# System User can't access python packages

Tags: python, linux

I've just started using Ubuntu 18.04, and I'm trying to give a system user access to the python library mxnet, since if I run the command `sudo -u ggc_user bash -c 'python3 -c "import mxnet"'`, I simply get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mxnet'`.

I've installed mxnet via `python3.7 -m pip install --user mxnet`, and I've tried to give ggc_user permissions to use mxnet via `find /home/godwyn/.local/lib/python3.7 -type f -exec chmod a+r {} \;` `find /home/godwyn/.local/lib/python3.7 -type d -exec chmod a+x {} \;`, but with little success. Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: FWIW, those `find` commands are redundant. You can do the same thing with `chmod a+rx /home/godwyn/.local/lib/python3.7`

Comment: With `--user` you have installed the library just for yourself, outside the reach of other users. If you want it system-wide, install it system-wide, as `root` without `--user`.

Answer (score 0):

Giving read and execute access to just that directory won't do much, because the other user doesn't have access to the parent directories or subdirectories (most likely).

Instead, why not install the module as that user?

```
sudo -Hu ggc_user python3.7 -m pip install --user mxnet
```

You could also install the module system-wide instead, but [that's not recommended](https://askubuntu.com/a/1087677/301745).

Also, consider using a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: If it's not a shared system, there is no *specific* reason not to install packages system-wide, though many things are easier if you use virtual environments.

Comment: Running that command throws the error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/godwyn/.local/lib'. ` It also complains that `The directory '/home/godwyn/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.`. I've tried giving read and write permissions to ggc_user for `/home/godwyn/.local/lib` but that doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

Comment: @Wynelf153 Oh right, you need to use `sudo -H`. Edited to add.